# Textbox values and save to DataGridView, Windows Form C++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm currently working for my finals project, a simple pharmacy inventory system. I've been searching on how to save the values from the TextBoxes to DataGridview cells, but failed to search solutions for c++ mostly is c# and vb. Thanks

Comment: Have you already used `DataGridView` in your code? if yes, please share code that creates it.

Comment: Already figured it out. :) anyways thanks! cheers!